# How to use Visual Studio debugger visualizers built against a different framework version?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-debugging, target-framework

I compiled the ExpressionTreeVisualizer project found in the Visual Studio 2010 samples but when I try to use it in a .NET 3.5 project I get the exception below:

> Could not load file or assembly
>   'file:///C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft\Visual Studio
>   2010\Common7\Packages\Debugger\Visualizers\ExpressionTreeVisualizer.dll'
>   or one of its dependencies. This
>   assembly is built by a runtime newer
>   than the currently loaded runtime and
>   cannot be loaded.

The sample project had the TargetFrameworkVersion set to v4.0 and after changing it to v3.5 and building it now works in my project.

I changed the source code and project file and rebuilt it so that I now have two expression tree visualizers, one for v3.5 projects and one for v4.0 projects. Is there a better way?

Thanks!

Comment: If @michielvoo or anybody knows a solution, please share.